# When I click on the LinkButton, it doesn't call the function "LinkButton_Click"

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview, linkbutton

The LinkButton I need to do it on backend, so I unable to use the OnClientClick at frontend. Any idea how to solve it?

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Staff ID";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Staff Name";
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Position";
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Status";
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Phone";
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "Email";

            //Add an addition column, else cant add linkbutton at the last column
            e.Row.Controls.Add(tc);
        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //add linkbutton at every last column
            e.Row.Controls.Add(tc);
            LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
            link.ID = "lbEdit";
            link.Text = "Edit";
            e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(link);
            link.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Click);

            if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "Inactive")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "redCell";
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the LinkButton_Click function

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('It works!')</script>");
        Response.Redirect("~/product.aspx");
    }
```

or where can I paste my "link.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Click);"?

This is the <asp:GridView />

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="GridView"  ID="staffList" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound">

</asp:GridView>
```

The entire backend code

```
public partial class staff : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string sqlConn = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]);
    //LinkButton link = new LinkButton();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridView();
        }
    }

    private void BindGridView()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlConn);
        string sql = "SELECT * from Staff";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        staffList.DataSource = dt;
        staffList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Staff ID";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Staff Name";
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Position";
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Status";
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Phone";
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "Email";

            //Add an addition column, else cant add linkbutton at the last column
            e.Row.Controls.Add(tc);
        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //add linkbutton at every last column
            e.Row.Controls.Add(tc);
            link.ID = "lbEdit";
            link.Text = "Edit";
            e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(link);
            link.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Click);

            //maybe can create a for loop at here to store all data
            if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "Inactive")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "redCell";
            }
        }
        
    }

    protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('It works!')</script>");
        Response.Redirect("~/product.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1">  markup and the entire code behind. The linkButton creation looks fine. Something else in your code is affecting it.

Comment: While button click, Is page redirected to mentioned product.aspx?. If page redirected script for alert will not work.

Comment: I have updated my <asp:GridView ID="GridView1">. For the redirect part, I just use to test whether the function is working or not. If it works, it will redirect me to the product.aspx, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the code for the GridView binding code? Without full code to replicate the issue, it would be hard to tell what the issue is.

Comment: The GridView binding code is this right ?<asp:GridView CssClass="GridView"  ID="staffList" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound">
    </asp:GridView>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button, a PostBack occurs and Gridview binding will be lost and as well as the buttons links. The following saves the gridView.DataSource into session. Note the if (!IsPostPack) is removed:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["gvDS"] != null)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = Session["gvDS"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
            BindGridView();
   
   
}

private void BindGridView()
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlConn);
    string sql = "SELECT * from Staff";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    staffList.DataSource = dt;
    staffList.DataBind();
    
    Session["gvDS"] = GridView1.DataSource;  // save into session

}
```